# What does it mean to open an output file as both input and output?

Tags: c++

I see code like this sometimes:

```
ofstream of("out.txt", ofstream::in | ofstream::out);
```

Why is it being opened as both input and output? What sense does it make to do that?

Comment: If you want to read and write from the same file, that's a good start.

Comment: @elyashiv But that's an output file not an input file...

Comment: This is pretty senseless, it has to be a `std::fstream` for in- and output.

Comment: @Paranaix But I see people do this with `ofstream` and I'm confused.

Comment: @user2030677 The only possible usage I see is directly operating on the stream buffer, which supports input operations too then. But I rather think that the people writing such code have messed something up.

Comment: I am pretty sure, the ofstream ignores input

Comment: @EdHeal The point here is that it is a `std::ofstream` not a `std::fstream`

Comment: @Gasim: It doesn't "ignore" input; it simply doesn't define an input interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes one needs to read a file, do some processing, then update the original file with some new information. Opening the file for both input and output allows one to do that without closing and re-opening.

It also makes explicit one's intentions with regards to the file.

**EDIT**: My original answer didn't take into account that the OP's example uses `ofstream` instead of `fstream`. So …

Using `ofstream` with `std::in` doesn't make any sense. Are there reads performed on the stream? If not, perhaps the code when originally written used an `fstream`, which was later changed to an `ofstream`. It's the kind of thing that can creep into a code base that's in maintenance mode.

Comment: But this is an *output* file. I would expect bidirectional I/O to be done with `fstream`.

Comment: Right. Maybe the folks coding this way are confused ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using an `ofstream`, none of the input functions are available to you on the stream. Then opening the file in read-write mode isn't harmful, but it *is* pointless unless you're going to start hacking about with the underlying stream.

It's probably boilerplate, copy/pasted from some tutorial on the internet without the author actually understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

This means nothing for the actual streams. The `std::ios_base::in` openmode will simply be ignored. But for the underlying stream buffers, it *does* mean something to open as both input and output: For example, file stream and string stream buffers allow putback functionality, but it can only be used if the buffers' `std::ios_base::openmode` specifies output.