# So...is there a way to stop files from clearing automatically? (c++)

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

So i'm making an extremely simple guessing console game and i want to store data permanently in a file (highscore). However everytime i compile the file i'm using empties itself. Is there anyway to stop that?
I've tried a lot of thing which didn't work and i honestly don't know where the problem is. I'm guessing it has to do with the fin and fout but for others it seemed to work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

int hs;

//this would be the play_game() function, unrelated to the subject

int main()
{
    std::ofstream fout;
    fout.open("HS.txt");

    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("HS.txt");

    srand(time(NULL));

    //menu with 4 options, play, quit, help and highscore (which i'm working on)

    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: Check [`std::fstream::open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open), the `mode` parameter and `std::ios::app` specifically.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: This question is not a duplicate, because OP doesn't just want to append, they want to both read and to write.

Comment: as panta rei says, modify your `fout.open` command to `fout.open ("HS.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);`

Comment: _@Menelaus_ To process reading and writing from the same file ressource use just a single `std::fstream`, otherwise you'll need to synchronize your `fout` and `fin` via using the same `rdbuf()` pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't open your file twice in parallel with two streams. Also, a simple open-for-writing will not truncate your file, but will place you at the start of the file, so you'll be overwriting existing data; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61895932/1593077). You have to open files with the write mode.

You need to either:

1. Open your file for both input and output - and without truncating it; see: 
    [What does it mean to open an output file as both input and output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21076938/1593077) , or
2. Open your file for reading only when your app starts, and open it for writing, and write to it, when it exists (or every once-in-a-while for better resiliency).